# prevent android app from being installed on TV devices

Tags: android

i want to block users from installing app on their smart TVs. i implemented this code in my main activity but doesn't seem to prevent that.

```
if (checkIsTelevision()) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Not supported")
                    .setMessage("This app is not compatible with TV devices")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            MainActivity.this.finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .show();
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions for this,

1. While building the app at first step of selecting devices you can
   uncheck TV.
2. TV system cancels the installation if the manifest file    consists
   of a access to hardware sensors. so you can check for the    device
   type and set the value as true for tv and false for non-tv
   devices. refer [https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/hardware.html]